# Sphinx exact match error

Tags: sphinx

We have website that uses this query:

```
SELECT did, kid FROM top_keywords WHERE MATCH('@keyword "^EXAMPLE KEYWORD$"') LIMIT 0,
```

100;

It works great in 99% times, but with some encoding it doesn't work. Example:

```
SELECT did, kid FROM top_keywords WHERE MATCH('@keyword "^εργον$"') LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Produces error:

**ERROR 1064 (42000): index top_keywords: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting
TOK_KEYWORD or TOK_INT near 'εργον$"'**

My sphinx version is 2.0.6.

My only idea is that has something to do with [conf-charset-type](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried copy/pasting your word `εργον` into
http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder

It appears to be composed entirely of non-ascii UTF8 chars. (ie the codes are all 255+)

So, ALL those letters whould need to be in `charset_table` for it to work.

---

I'm guessing they are not in you `charset_table` (just setting `charset_type=utf8` is NOT enough), in which case they are completely stripped, so the query becomes

```
SELECT did, kid FROM top_keywords WHERE MATCH('@keyword "^ $"') LIMIT 0, 100;
```

... as the letters are all taken as seperators, which clearly leaves you an invalid query.

---

Unfortunately I can't give you any good references for charset_table for international support (dont know any!), but perhaps start on the wiki http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?do=search&id=charset_table